# Prompt for user input on Command prompt using Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, user-input, command-prompt

One of my team uses DSS for running javascript on the windows command prompt for some chip designing purpose.

Now there requirement is to prompt a user for an input on command prompt and they want it to do using Javascript function.

I have tried alert and prompt but I have a feeling that it is not possible to prompt the user for an input on command prompt using Javascript.

The script is used of some kind of CCS thing.

Can anyone please guide us as to how can we prompt for a user input on command prompt using JAVASCRIPT.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `StdIn`:

```
WScript.StdOut.Write('please enter your input: ');
var myInput = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I am getting the following error after using it...Wscript is not defined...  Can you tell me what should I do??

Comment: use W*S*cript -> it's case sensitive (your s is lowercase)

Comment: That was a typo from me here while posting.I have used WScript itself as mentioned in your post...So I am still getting the same error.Do I need to include any kind of file ??

Comment: Try this: copy both lines into a file called `input.js`. Open a `cmd`-window in the directory where you saved the file. Type `cscript input.js<enter>` and see what happens...

Comment: Then I fear I can't help you further. It works here (in a cmd-window, on win7 64bit).

Comment: Have you included any package any important file in order to run this kind of file..

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using windows, the easiest way is to use JScript engine. It can use almost all windows internal functionality.

Here's an explanation on how to use input/output:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c61dx86d%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/Handling-User-Input-in-WSH/
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156599.aspx